# Cql time datatype to java time datatype

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am new to the Cassandra. I developed a table named customer in which one of the column is time. So it give it's data type as time itself in CQL shell. But in my spring boot application in model i given it as String time. So when i executed the code by calling the get URL in postman it's shows as, in CQL shell time as 13:12:56.000 where as in postman it showing something like 48654000000000.

So my question is why it's does not showing as like in CqQL shell?

Comment: CQL 'time' Value is encoded as a 64-bit signed integer representing the number of nanoseconds since midnight. So I guess it is a long internally, and you just get that long. Shell also gets the long, but it also converts it to string (just like you would convert System.nanoTime() to string)

Answer (score 0):

As it's mentioned in the comment, the data is encoded as 64-bit long number representing milliseconds, and CQLSH is doing conversion when displaying data.

When you use the Java driver, the `timestamp` type could be mapped either to `java.util.Date` with [default mappings](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/#cql-to-java-type-mapping), or it could be mapped to Java 8's or Joda's `Instant` if you use [optional codecs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/custom_codecs/extras/#temporal-types).

Regarding postman - it's hard to say precisely why this happens on their side.